# how to get the response from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a below data and i want to show only few fields  `_id, courseBy` in my response

```
const result =  [{
_id: 6104106f3ff78f39b81bf143,
category: 't-shirts',
courseBy: ' shivangi joshi',
thumbnail: 'uploads\\shirt.jpg',
about: ' shirts',
},
{
 _id: 610410763ff78f39b81bf147,
 category: 'watches',
 courseBy: ' shivangi joshi',
 thumbnail: 'uploads\\shirt.jpg',
 about: ' shirts',
}]
```

Response data:-

```
 res.status(200).send({
   statusCode: "200",
     "_id":result[0]._id,
     "courseBy": reslut[0]._courseBy
});
```

here i'm only getting single record but not the both the records please help me thanks in advance

Comment: So why are you just returning one thing if you want many? Sounds like you want array map and convert the one array into a different array.

Comment: “*i'm only getting single record but not the both the records*” Can you point to a spot in your code which you believe should print both records?

Answer (score 2):

```
res.status(200).send({
    statusCode: "200",
    data: result.map(({ _id, courseBy }) => ({ _id, courseBy }))
 });
```